# cleaner way to call change event function in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a working function that's embedded in `select` tag like so.

```
<select onChange="myfunc()" id="some_id">
```

Obviously, when the drop-down option changes, `myfunc()` will run and pickup the updated option value.

But since I don't want to mix javascript and html, so is there a much cleaner way to do this rather than embedding the function in the `select` tag?

I understand adding an event listener might be the option but I don't really know how to make it work to accomplish the same task.

I tried using the code below but so far no luck. the value does not change.

```
addEventListener("change", myfunc, false);
```

Comment: I can but I want to use pure js as much as possible.

Comment: Is `addEventListener` not a method of a DOM object, rather than a free-standing function? (Don't ask me, I use jQuery.) In any case your `addEventListener` code must be missing something, since it doesn't even mention the DOM object in question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok if you want to do that in a seperate file. Include the jQuery and the *seperate_file.js* in your docuemnt.

Once you're done. In the seperate file write this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('some_id').change(function () {
      alert("Change handled in other file");
   });
});
```

This would work for you. If the linking is correct. You'll get the alert saying the message passed to it.

Comment: is it possible using pure js (without using jquery)?

Comment: No I don't think Pure JS would do that.

Comment: jQuery is built on pure javascript. If jQuery can do it, then javascript can do it by itself.